# TabLayout/Tab logic for multiple activities

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I wonder if its possible to use tab logic to switch between activities as each tab would represent single `Activity`. I don't want to use `Fragments`, because `Fragments` as component caused a lot of issues in my previous project and I don't trust that component at all(transaction bugs, missing context are main issues). With tabs there would be problem to show single `TabLayout` for all activities, so I need some parent component for that. Because I don't want for my `TabLayout` to flicker or disappear for a moment between `Activity` switches. There was `TabActivity` class, but thats deprecated for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, I'm absolutely sure you're on the wrong way
First of all, multiplying activities is the worse way of creating applications. It makes your app less productive
I highly recommend you to read best google practices on how to use Jetpack Library to avoid bugs and create a nice app.

[Jetpack Navigation with FRAGMENTS](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started)

[Tabs with ViewPager2 and FRAGMENTS](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2)